# Number of times fork() is called in this code?

Tags: c, fork

Here is my code that i got from my institute's previous year question paper.

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<unistd.h>
    int main() 
    {
       fork();
       fork() && fork() || fork();
       fork();
       printf("forked ");
       return 0;
    }
```

I got 20 times printed "forked" as output. Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: I have removed part of your question because it is duplicate and it is within your reach to research yourself how && and || work.

Comment: Some questions make it clear that the poster hasn't bothered to do their own studying. Such questions are not welcome. Please read the guidelines on how to ask good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: specifically look up short circuit operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, under normal circumstances (system is not low on resources), you'll get 20 `forked` printouts.  Why?

The first fork is unconditional, so we'll get two times whatever happens next.  Same with the third one, so we'll get a total of four times whatever we get from the second group of forks, which if we add parentheses for clarity, is this:

```
(fork() && fork()) || fork();
```

How many from here?  Well, fork will return zero (false) to one process and non-zero to the other.  So:

```
        -> true
 true -/-> false -\-> true
                   -> false

 false ------------\-> true
                    -> false
```

Within each line is a single process as it proceeds through the calls.  You can see there are five lines, so five processes.  Multiply that by the four we determined up above, and you get 20.